# Google Analytics - Get All Events Occurrences With Exact Time

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm kind of new to google analytics. I have a site where every time a logged user sends a request to the server I'm sending the event to google analytics.
This event contains this fields: {category: 'api_request', action: request url, label: the logged user id'}.
I am wondering if it is possible to see all sent requests for a specific route for a specific user. I will like to get the specific date-time of each request for this route.
I tried to do this in google analytics and found that I can group by action & date, but it doesn't contain the exact time (make sense). Can I achieve this behavior with google analytics or ga-dev-tools?

Answer (score 2):

### Be aware of high cardinality

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en

If you start to collect unique data timestamp with every hit, you can soon reach cardinality limit, taht is **50.000 unique dimension values perday**. Once you reach this limit, all other collected values will be treated as other.

Consider that day have 86400 seconds.

```
Date.now()
```

Date now return time in miliseconds. So every hit will probably have different timestamp and you will reach limit soon.

So if you want to do this, use at least seconds.

```
Date.now() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure (and send on each event) a custom dimension hit level that contains the current timestamp (i.e. Date.now()).

Comment: Thank you very much, is there another way? maybe to do this from the ga-dev-tools?

Comment: Configure the custom dimension and send the hits with the ga-dev-tools with this cdX value.